# Change CSS property on click on buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hy,
Please can any one help me to do this task. i really need it so much.

i want to change the class style of the button (witch is a link) by clicking on it.
The buttons are contained on a dynamic child div witch will change every time. the name of the dynamic child div will stay the same every time.

Note: Only one single child div will displayed  in the parent div.

This is the style code:

```
.btn_child              {display:block;  margin:-1px; border:1px solid; background-color:#428bca; border-color:#357ebd; text-align:left; padding-left:15px;  line-height:30px; }
.btn_child:hover        {background-color:#3276b1; border-color:#285e8e; }
.btn_child_selected     {background-color:#3276b1; border-color:#285e8e; }
```

This is the html code:

```
<div id="parent" class="parent_class"> 
<!--this is a dynamic content and the ID will change. only the name will still the same-->
<div id="dynamic_child1" name="child">
<a class="btn_child" target="_blank" href="" > link1        </a>
<a class="btn_child" target="_blank" href="" > link2        </a>
<a class="btn_child" target="_blank" href="" > link3        </a>
</div>
</div>
```

IMPORTANT: By clicking on the next button, the old one will return to default style and the new one style will be changed.

This is a link. it may explain more: http://jsfiddle.net/c1znyrw5/

Comment: You haven't added any javascript at all?

Comment: If you want to switch between the default and the new class you can use [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).

Comment: yes i already use it, but it didn't work for me. i think because the children is  <a> not <div>

Comment: @HoussemChlegou What do you mean, there is no JS in your example?

Comment: Also note if they are supposed to go to a new page, and the new page is the page you would like to change you are going to need to use something like `localStorage`. Otherwise if you don't want them to go to a new page use `event.preventDefault` on your `click` event.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek This is my work when i use  the toggleClass() function. link: https://jsfiddle.net/c1znyrw5/1/

Comment: @HoussemChlegou I mean the jQuery version, click the link in my previous comment. Also you never ran your function, and note that your function will have them all be `btn_child_selected`.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Ok i will try with it. i will let you know what happened with me. think you.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek i checked the link what you send it to me, but i don't want to add css class, i want to "change" (replace or set) some css commands

Comment: @HoussemChlegou Then use Muhammed answer. Also you said directly in your question "i want to change the class". Be more clear on what you want.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek i also said that there are a reset when we click on the next one. i made it and i find the answer. i post it you can check it. and i really want to think you and think everyone else who helped me with his ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I make it done like I want it! If anyone is interested with this thing, here is the solution:

```
<script><!--jquery script-->
$('.parent_class').on('click','.btn_child',function () {
$('.btn_child').removeClass('btn_child_selected');
$(this).addClass('btn_child_selected')
});
</script>
```

You can also check this link where it's done: http://jsfiddle.net/c1znyrw5/3/

I want to think you all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

you can use jquery .on for click event binding of the dynamically generated child and inside that event use to change the style of the respective control

```
$('#parent').on('click', '.btn_class', function() { 
    this.addClass("someCss");
});
```

Comment: please can you give me the full result? i'm new in Js and i don't have big ideas about jquery

Comment: corrected the code as per your need. Please change 'someCss' to the class you have.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#divid').click(function() {
    $('#div').css({
        'background-color': 'red',
        'color': 'white',
        'font-size': '44px'
    });
});
```

where #divid refer to button and #div refer to the div you want change the css

OR we can creat a css class and use addClass method instead of css method

```
$('#divid').click(function() {
        $('#div').addClass('cssclass');
    });
```

Comment: please can you give me the full result? i'm new in Js and i don't have big ideas about jquery

Answer (score 1):

Define a class in css and on button click add that class to particular element. Assume your class name is "active". Then your code will be like this.

```
    $('#divid').click(function() {
    $('#div').addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: i want also to reset it again when clicked on another button. i make it done yesterday you can chek it: http://jsfiddle.net/c1znyrw5/3/ and think you.